# Setting Geowebcache to a long time expiration

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have a Disk blobstore to cache my WMS layers. Fine.
Now I need to set it to a very long ( a month? ) time to expire the disk cache because I have just a few users using and is not enough to keep my tiles cached.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/expiretiles.html (URL updated):

```
<expireCacheList>
  <expirationRule minZoom="0"  expiration="14400" />
  <expirationRule minZoom="10" expiration="7200" />
</expireCacheList>
```

> expiration:
> Defines the number of seconds a tile remains valid on the server. Subsequent requests will result in a new tile being fetched. The
> default is to cache forever. Special expiration values are -1 to
> disable caching and -2 to never expire.

I don't understood... must I do nothing (`The default is to cache forever`) or set an entry to a `-2` value?

Anyway... I think I just need to fill the caching expiration time in `Tile Caching` tab for each Layer.

Comment: It should be the same (no setting or -2). I personally prefer writing the value, even if it is the default, as it is easier to see/review in the future without remembering all defaults, and it is more secured should the default change